# How to change slug if same string is stored in it?

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls

I am working with slug on my model. Although, the entries for slug are not unique. When I try to go to a url containing slug, it says get() returned more than one object and I understand that it is because the entries are not unique. How am I supposed to change the slug a bit, if identical entries occur?

model

```
 class Cabin(models.Model):

     centre_name = models.ForeignKey(Centre, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
     code = models.CharField(max_length=8, unique=True, default=unique_rand)
     total_seats = models.IntegerField(blank='False')
     category=models.CharField(max_length=100, default=False)
     booked_date=models.DateField(blank='False')
     released_date=models.DateField(blank='False')
     price=models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=None)
     slug = models.SlugField(unique=False,default=None,blank=True)

     objects = UserManager()

     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.category)
        super(Client, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all it might be better to set `unique=True`, such that this can never happen, furthermore you can :

```
class Cabin(models.Model):
    centre_name = models.ForeignKey(Centre, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    code = models.CharField(max_length=8, unique=True, default=unique_rand)
    total_seats = models.IntegerField(blank='False')
    category=models.CharField(max_length=100, default=False)
    booked_date=models.DateField(blank='False')
    released_date=models.DateField(blank='False')
    price=models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=None)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,default=None,blank=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        slug = originalslug = slugify(self.category)
        i = 0
        while Cabin.objects.exist(slug=slug):
            slug = '{}{}'.format(originalslug, i)
            i += 1
        self.slug = slug
        super(Client, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

We here thus increment `i` until we found a slug that is not yet used.

Note that there exists an [**`AutoSlugField`**](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/field_extensions.html#current-database-model-field-extensions) in the [**`django-extensions`** package [PyPi]](https://pypi.org/project/django-extensions/), that automates this slug procedure. For example:

```
from django.db import models
from django_extensions.db.fields import AutoSlugField

class Cabin(models.Model):
    centre_name = models.ForeignKey(Centre, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    code = models.CharField(max_length=8, unique=True, default=unique_rand)
    total_seats = models.IntegerField(blank='False')
    category=models.CharField(max_length=100, default=False)
    booked_date=models.DateField(blank='False')
    released_date=models.DateField(blank='False')
    price=models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=None)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='category')

    objects = UserManager()
```